# Cannot resolve symbol in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, twitter4j

I am working on integrating twitter with my android application, I am using twitter4j library to do this.

I have added the twitter4j library files and put it in a folder libs and added compile dependency in build.gradle inside app folder

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'
}
```

but I am still not able to use this library
[image]

Comment: Did you build the project again after adding the dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this at "repositories" on your buildscript.

```
repositories { mavenCentral() }
```

Answer (score 3):

In the Gradle drawer to the right, could you hit the refresh button to see if that helps? Also, the dependencies block that you've pasted above doesn't contain a directive for twitter4j - did you happen to simply miss it out in the question, or is it really missing from the `gradle.build` file?

Comment: ohh I missed to mention: